# Dynamically add CORS allowedOrigins based on condition Azure Arm template

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I am trying to add allowedOrigin dynamically based on prod or non prod environments. Have tried few ways, but none of these are working.  For Prod, we want only 3 domains to be allowed, but for lower environments we want to allow any origins. Could someone please help.

```
"variables": { 
   "corsAllowedUrls": [
        "https://www.example.com",
        "https://app2.example.com",
        "https://m2.example.com"
    ]
 }
 .......
 "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
 "siteConfig": {
      "cors": {
        "allowedOrigins": [
          "[if(equals(parameters('azureEnvironment'),'prod'), variables('corsAllowedUrls'), '*')]"
        ]
      },
```

Second Option, this works for the prod, but for other environments, it add three rows, which randomly works and randomly don't work.

```
"siteConfig": {
      "cors": {
        "allowedOrigins": [
          "[if(equals(parameters('azureEnvironment'),'prod'), 'https://ww2.example.com', '*')]",
          "[if(equals(parameters('azureEnvironment'),'prod'), 'https://app2.example.com', '')]",
          "[if(equals(parameters('azureEnvironment'),'prod'), 'https://m2.example.com', '')]"
        ]
      }
```

I have also tried by sending a comma separated string and using the split function.
The ideal could have been to have a wild card, but it seems these are not supported in Azure.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try  this :

```
"variables": { 
  "corsAllowedProdUrls": [
    "https://www.example.com",
    "https://app2.example.com",
    "https://m2.example.com"
  ],
  "corsAllowedDevUrls": [
    "*"
  ]
}
.......
"type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
"siteConfig": {
  "cors": {
    "allowedOrigins": "[if(equals(parameters('azureEnvironment'),'prod'), variables('corsAllowedProdUrls'), variables('corsAllowedDevUrls'))]"
  },
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Maurico, I only tried the second option here and it worked. I have doubt about the first one, as it will be array inside array, which was the case earlier for not working. Could you please edit the answer, so that I can accept it. Thanks a alot.